# Complex structure of int32_t and char array in python ctypes

Tags: python, c, function, structure, ctypes

I am trying to create a structure to use in a C library provided (DLL),
How the following structure (given in the documentation) can be defined?

```
#define A 10
#define B 20
typedef struct
{
int32_t size;
int32_t num;
char buf1[A][B];
char buf2[A][B];
char buf3[A][B];
} INSTRUCT;
```

My attempt to define it in python using ctypes was like so:

```
from ctypes import*

char_buff1 = ((c_char * 10) * 20)
char_buff2 = ((c_char * 10) * 20)
char_buff3 = ((c_char * 10) * 20)


class INSTRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_=[("size",c_int32),("num",c_int32),("buf1",char_buff1),("buf2",char_buff2),("buf3",char_buff3)]
```

Can `int32_t` be replaced with `c_int_32` in ctypes?
Is it correct way to define the structure?

Then I tried to feed the pointer of the structure to the DLL function and check what it returns as follows:

```
dlllib = CDLL("some.dll")
somefunction = dlllib.some_function
somefunction.argtypes = [POINTER(INSTRUCT)]

INSTRUCT().size
INSTRUCT().num
print(np.ctypeslib.as_array(INSTRUCT().buf1))
```

However, I can only the return is `0` and unmodified by the function -- equal to the one defined before the C function call.

I am not sure at which stage the problem occurs, however, there are no errors, the code executes normally.
Unfortunately, I don't have the C code available, only the input parameters for the function.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array definition is wrong.  In `ctypes`, the array indices need to be reversed to index the array the way C does.  For example, the equivalent of `char buf[x][y]` in Python with `ctypes` is `buf = (c_char * y * x)()`.  Note that the bounds are reversed.  Otherwise, your definition was correct.

Note that using `c_char` will return text characters for array values.  If you want integers, use `c_int8`.  I'll use the latter below.

Example:

```py
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

A,B = 10,20
ARRAY = c_int8 * B * A   # build as B,A

class INSTRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_=[("size",c_int32),
              ("num",c_int32),
              ("buf1",ARRAY),
              ("buf2",ARRAY),
              ("buf3",ARRAY)]

i = INSTRUCT()
i.buf1[9][19] = 1  # access indices as A,B
print(np.ctypeslib.as_array(i.buf1))
```

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]  # 1 in correct location
```

Your example of accessing used `INSTRUCT()` which creates a new, zeroed object each time.  Create a single instance and pass it to a function like so:

```py
dlllib = CDLL("some.dll")
somefunction = dlllib.some_function
somefunction.argtypes = [POINTER(INSTRUCT)]

i = INSTRUCT()          # make an instance
somefunction(byref(i))  # byref() passes address of a ctypes object.
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks a lot, yes i did not know about the revised order! Although, I need the 3 arrays (bufs) in the structure to be `char` not `int8`, if I tried your example `char buf[x][y]` --> `(c_char * y * x)()` I got an error `TypeError: second item in _fields_ tuple (index 2) must be a C type`

Comment: @Werefkin use `c_char * 20 *10` for a type. The trailing parentheses make it an instance. In my example change `ARRAY` to `c_char * B * A`.